# Powershell ForEach If "True" do a Delete

Tags: powershell, sccm

The following code seems to work but takes a bit to run on just one machine, also I cannot test it completely as some if the objects aren't there.  I would appreciate any advice on if I am going about the process correctly or if there is a simpler/faster way to do this.

```
$SCCMObj = get-wmiobject -query "select * from SMS_R_SYSTEM WHERE Name='$env:computername'" -computername [SMSServer] -namespace "ROOT\SMS\site_[SiteCode]"
$PSB = $SCCMObj.psbase
$PSBSR = $SCCMObj.psbase.syncroot
$PSBLgth = $SCCMObj.psbase.length
$SCCMArray = @($PSB, $PSBSR, $PSBLgth)
$SCCMArray | ForEach {If ($_ -ne $Null) {$SCCMObj.psbase.delete()}}
```

The intent is to find any/all SCCM computer objects residing in the DB and delete each one via PowerShell.  The code came from: http://marco-difeo.de/2011/08/02/sccm-delete-computer-object-via-powershell-and-wmi/
Thanks so much!

Comment: Unclear what the problem is and what your question is.

Comment: I put this together, but I am unsure it works 100% as I am learning powershell.  I try to test every possible scenario, which I cannot do with each one of these objects when they are not there.  It did delete the $PSB object as there was an object present for it.  The others were Null.  I would appreciate another set of eyes on this to make sure I have the foreach set up properly to handle the others if they were not Null.  Plus the latency aspect of running this (maybe 10sec on one machine) make me wonder if this is more complex than it needs to be.  Thanks!

Comment: Does it execute faster if you were to add `$Date = Get-Date` at the top of your script and replace the commands you have in your foreach currently with `write-host $Date`?  This will help determine where the slow down is.  It's either in the enumeration of the array or that you're creating a new instance of `$SCCMObj.psbase` on each run.  Also try reusing your `$PSB` like this `$PSB.delete()`.  Assuming it's not the actual command itself.  Also, does that method support an array as input?

Comment: Well I tried the code today and it was much faster, thanks.  So, my overall question is, will the scriptblock in the foreach statement run against the array if "True" pops up for any instance in the array?  And does the deletion appear to be done at the correct object level for each object in the array?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the original blog post you mention, I would handle this like so:

```
if ($SCCMObj.psbase.syncroot) {
    $SCCMObj.psbase.syncroot | Foreach { $_.psbase.delete() }
}
else {
    SCCMObj.psbase.delete()
}
```